# Child Event Listener Keep adding itself in recyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to show messages between two users in a recyclerview . Everything goes alright until i restart the activity in either device of the both when i restart the activity a child event listener is added and i see multiple message in place of one that i sent and when i restart my activity without sending any message it shows me original number of messages and if i send or recieve a message again i see multiple messages and the cycle repeats.I have tried removing listener in onDestroy and onStop but no use.

[image]

[image]

Code

> MessageActivity.java(updated)

```
    public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CircleImageView profile_image;
    TextView user_name;

    FirebaseFirestore fstore;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseUser fuser;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    ValueEventListener mValueEventListener;

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ImageButton imageButton;
    EditText textsend;
    String userID;

    MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    List<Chat> mChat;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    DatabaseReference Chatreference;

    String TAG = "MyTag";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fstore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


        profile_image = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        user_name = findViewById(R.id.username);
        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        textsend = findViewById(R.id.text_send);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        String userid = intent.getStringExtra("userid");
        //String username = intent.getStringExtra("UserName");


        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

        mValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                user_name.setText(user.getFirst());
                Log.d(TAG, "Value Event Listener called");

                if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")) {
                    profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                } else {
                    //and this
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageURL()).into(profile_image);
                }


                readMessages(fuser.getUid(), userid, user.getImageURL());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

        reference.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);


        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String msg = textsend.getText().toString();
                textsend.setText("");
                if (!msg.equals("")) {
                    sendMessage(fuser.getUid(), userid, msg);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "Empty messages cant be send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void sendMessage(String sender, final String receiver, String message) {

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("sender", sender);
        hashMap.put("receiver", receiver);
        hashMap.put("message", message);


        DatabaseReference Chatreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");

        String key = Chatreference.push().getKey();
        Chatreference.child(key).setValue(hashMap);


    }

    private void readMessages(String myid, String userid, String imageurl) {

        mChat = new ArrayList<>();

        Chatreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");

        mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                Chat chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

                if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myid) && chat.getSender().equals(userid) ||
                        chat.getReceiver().equals(userid) && chat.getSender().equals(myid)) {

                    chat.setMessageId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    mChat.add(chat);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Child_Event_Listener_Called");
                    Log.d(TAG, "msg " + chat.getMessage());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "msg " + chat.getMessage());

                messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this, mChat, imageurl);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                Chat chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                chat.setMessageId(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                mChat.remove(chat);
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };


        Chatreference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Chatreference.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);


    }
}
```

> MessageAdapter.java

```
    public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public static  final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 0;
    public static  final int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT = 1;

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Chat> mChat;
    String imageurl;

    FirebaseUser fuser;

    public MessageAdapter(Context mContext, List<Chat> mChat,String imageurl) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mChat = mChat;
        this.imageurl=imageurl;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == MSG_TYPE_RIGHT) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_right, parent, false);

            return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        }
        else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_left, parent, false);

            return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(view);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Chat chat=mChat.get(position);
        holder.show_message.setText(chat.getMessage());

        if (imageurl.equals("default")){
            holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        } else {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(imageurl).into(holder.profile_image);
        }

        holder.show_message.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                String message_id=chat.getMessageId();
                Task<Void> task = Utils.removeUser(message_id);
                task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Message Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                return true;
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mChat.size();
        }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

         public TextView show_message;
         public ImageView profile_image;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        show_message=itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_message);
        profile_image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        fuser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (mChat.get(position).getSender().equals(fuser.getUid())){
            return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT;
        }
        else {
            return MSG_TYPE_LEFT;
        }
    }
}
```

> Chat.java

```
    public class Chat {
    private String sender;
    private String receiver;
    private  String message;
    String MessageId;

    public Chat(String sender, String receiver, String message) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Chat() {
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return MessageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        MessageId = messageId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Chat){
            Chat chat=(Chat) obj;
            return this.MessageId.equals(chat.getMessageId());}
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you you can use the addListenerForSingleValueEvent() method to simplify this scenario:

```
reference.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);
```

Other advice

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats").child("RoomId");
```

I think it is better. You don't need to listen to other chats

Comment: I have tried using this when i add Single Event Listener to see the new  message which i have recieved i have to close the activity and than come back to the activity to see the message

Comment: Can you please help me in making this work with ChildEventListener because it gives me a bit more flexibility to in operations that i can use on these messages

Comment: @RaviMalik problem is not listener type. I am using childListener to. It works fine.

Comment: I have updated my message activity code and now i am removing child event listener on ondestroy and it didn't helped can you please check if i did it right

Comment: Why didn't you use Single Event Listener. Because it triggers after every sent message

Comment: i changed the value event listener to Single event Listener and it worked thanks a i dont know what i was doing wrong last time when i used single event listener

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Good luck. Happy coding.